# Search bar will only show first Cell in detail view

Tags: swift

I have created a TableView with a Search Bar in Swift.
I have created 3 searchable objects. (131, 132, 137)
When i search for 137 and press 137(which is the only option to press), i still get to 131 detailView. Anyone know why? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

let TitleList = ["131","132","137"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
    self.tableView.reloadData()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.LabelTitle.text = TitleList[indexPath.row]
    cell.CellDescription.text = DescriptionList[indexPath.row]


    let imagename = UIImage(named: ImageList[indexPath.row])
    cell.CellImage.image = imagename


    if self.resultSearchController.active {
        cell.LabelTitle?.text = self.filteredfarger[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        cell.LabelTitle?.text = self.TitleList[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell


}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredfarger.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (self.TitleList as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredfarger = array as! [String]
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedViewController
        if let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let Title = TitleList[indexpath.row] as String
            VC.SentData1 = Title
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you do the search the row for 137 is 0, and then in `prepareForSegue` you use the `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` (which means `indexPath.row == 0`) to get the title data. Try doing something like in your `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath` function where you check if `resultSearchController` is active or not, and if it is use `filteredfarger` instead of `TitleList`. Something like this maybe:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedViewController
        if let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            if self.resultSearchController.active {
                let Title = self.filteredfarger[indexpath.row]
                VC.SentData1 = Title
            }
            else {
                let Title = TitleList[indexpath.row] as String
                VC.SentData1 = Title
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Better yet, you already give the cell some info, why not just use that, kinda like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedViewController
        if let cell = sender as? TableViewCell {
            VC.SentData1 = cell.LabelTitle.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me how my new code would look like?
Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day. You are my Hero.

Comment: Check out the edit, it'll save you a few lines of code.